# SOA Suite 11g One way process. How to handle errors in bpel If the service you are consuming is not avaiable ( down for some reason).

Tags: web-services, soa

SOA Suite 11g One way process. How to handle errors in bpel If the service you are consuming is not avaiable ( down for some reason). Also any idea, what other errors we need to handle.

Little overview of my service.

My BPEL(2.0) will be consuming two services and the person who will consume my service will do a one way call and my service will be one way as well. so getting hard time to figure out how to handle the errors.

New to SOA. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If the external service is not available a remote fault will be thrown you can you a fault policy file to retry the call three times at 5 minute intervals. If this fails you should go to the human intervention mechanism where once the external service is up someone in the support team can retry the service and everything will continue processing.

[For details on how to configure the fault policies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/integration.1111/e10224/bp_faults.htm)